# Grails Spring Security - reload session variables on relogin after session timeout

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-security, session-variables

I'm using spring security core in my grails application. My app has lots of ajax calls which call controllers. Controllers in turn, depend on some session variables to fulfil the request. I'm currently able to correctly display the ajax login form on session timeout. However, it creates a new session with only the newly created user object. All other objects stored in session are lost.

Is there a way to reload session variables after a user logs back in after session time out?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Spring Security.  You're container is destroying the session.  The lack of the user object is what triggers spring security to tell you, you need to log in again. If you don't want to lose session data, persist it to the database/cookie.

Comment: the purpose of the session scope is that it's wiped when the session ends. if you need to share data between sessions, you should rethink your architecture and persist the data in a database (server side), or  a cookie (client side).

Comment: Thanks Gregg and moeTi. You guys got me thinking in the right direction. Since I have just a couple of variable tacked into the session, I might as well put them as part of global ajax setup and put them in every request, effectively making my application state-less. This architecture will have another benefit of being load balancer friendly since now any of our servers can handle the request.

Comment: Gregg, I'm kinda new to Stackoverflow, if you could post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the purpose of the session scope is that it's wiped when the session ends. if you need to share data between sessions, you should rethink your architecture and persist the data in a database (server side), or a cookie (client side)

*(moved from comments into an answer)*